# Taylor polynomials to approximate value

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

Use the second order Taylor polynomials $P_2(x)$ for the given functions about the point specified to approximate the indicated value. Estimate the error and write the smallest interval you can be sure contains the value. Calculator not allowed.

Well I know the formula

$P_2(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(x)}{2}(x-a)^2$

But as soon as I try to solve any equations everything just become wrong and impossible to solve without calculator and even with calculator I get the wrong answer.

1. $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ about 8; approximate   $9^{1/3}$
2. $f(x)=\frac{1}{x} $ about 1; approximate $\frac{1}{1.02}$

If I understood it correctly:

$1: a=8\quad x=9^{1/3}$

$2:a=1\quad x=\frac{1}{1.02}$

Comment: ... and $P_2(x)$ in both cases? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ and $a=8$, then$$P_2(x)=2+\frac{x-8}{12}-\frac{(x-8)^2}{288}.$$ Therefore $P(9)=\frac{599}{288}$. The error has the form $\frac{f^{(3)}(\zeta)}{3!}(9-8)^2=\frac{f^{(3)}(\zeta)}6$, for some $\zeta\in[8,9]$. Since $f^{(3)}(x)=\frac{10x^{-8/3}}{27}$, which is a decreasing function, $\frac{f^{(3)}(\zeta)}6\leqslant\frac{10\times8^{-8/3}}{6\times27}=\frac 5{20\,736}\simeq0.00024$.

Can you deal with the other exercise now?

Comment: You calculated $P(9)$ but I need to $P(9^{1/3})$. Is there something I have missed out on?

Comment: If I understood this correctly after some further research. If the number a we can calculate has the same exponent as the number we want to calculate then we can simply ignore the exponent from the number we want to calculate. Both $x^{1/3}$ and $9^{1/3}$ has the same exponent and therefore this is possible? This explains so much, thank you! :)

Comment: @JavaProgrammer No, you don't need $P(9^{1/3})$. What you need is an approximate value of $9^{1/3}$ and that is what I provided. Note that $\sqrt[3]9\simeq2.08008$, whereas the number that I got is $\frac{599}{288}\simeq2.07986$. Do you believe that this was just a big coincidence?